# Symmetric positive semi-definite matrices and norm inequalities

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, normed-spaces

If $A$ and $B$ are symmetric positive semi-definite matrices such that $A \succeq B$  (i.e., $A-B$ is p.s.d.), does the following hold: $\Vert A\Vert_2 \geq \Vert B \Vert_2$?

Here $\Vert \cdot \Vert_2$ is the induced/operator 2-norm defined as

$\| A \|_2 = \sup \limits _{x \ne 0} \frac{\| A x\| _2}{\|x\|_2}$

Comment: If positive semidefinitness includes symmetry, then yes. Check the eigen values of $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Yes they are symmetric, but I don't know how the eigenvalues of $A-B$ are related to the eigenvalues of $A$ and $B$..

Comment: $\|A\|_2$ is the largest eigenvalue of $A$...

Comment: Yes, but how do we know that's larger than the largest eigenvalue of $B$? All we know is that the eigenvalues of $A-B$ are all non-negative, but there is no obvious way to relate these sets of eigenvalues to each other except when, e.g., $A$ and $B$ are both diagonal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $A$ and $B$ are symmetric:

Let $u$ be an unit eigen vector to eigen value $\|B\|_2$ of $B$. Then, we have
$$ 0 \le u^T(A-B) u = u^T A u - u^T B u \le \|A\|_2 - \|B\|_2. $$