# Frobenius norm and symmetric positive definite matrices: Is it true that $\|A_1\cdots A_n\|_F \leq \|B_1\cdots B_n\|_F$ where $0 < A_i^2< B_i^2$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, normed-spaces, matrix-norms

Consider symmetric positive definite matrices $A_1, \cdots, A_n$ and $B_1,\cdots,B_n$ such that $$A_i^2 < B_i^2$$ for $i \in [n]$, where $A <B$ means that $B-A$ is positive definite.

Is it true that $$\|A_1\cdots A_n\|_F \leq \|B_1\cdots B_n\|_F$$ where $\|A\|_F$ denotes the Frobenius norm of matrix $A$?

According to  [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4567285/133206), the inequality is true for $n=2$.

If it is not true for $n>2$, is there a sufficient condition under which it can be true?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not true. When the constraint $A_i^2<B_i^2$ is relaxed to $A_i^2\le B_i^2$, there is a random counterexample:
$$
\begin{aligned}
&A_1=\pmatrix{0.2144&0\\ 0&0.8922},
\ A_2=\pmatrix{0.3455&-0.2883\\ -0.2883&0.8029},
\ A_3=\pmatrix{0.7817&-0.2633\\ -0.2633&0.5608},\\
&B_1=\pmatrix{0.273970&0.013878\\ 0.013878&0.897168},
\ B_2=\pmatrix{0.4402&-0.2299\\ -0.2299&0.8401},
\ B_3=\pmatrix{0.7818&-0.2635\\ -0.2635&0.5620}\\
\end{aligned}
$$
where
$$
\frac{\|A_1A_2A_3\|_F}{\|B_1B_2B_3\|_F}-1=0.020842>0.
$$
So, if we replace each $B_i$ by $(B_i^2+\epsilon I)^{1/2}$ for a sufficiently small $\epsilon>0$, we obtain a counterexample with $A_i^2<B_i^2$.

Counterexamples like this (subject to the relaxed constraint) can be obtained easily by rejection sampling. Here is my Octave/Matlab script:

```
n=2;    % order of the matrices
t=.05;  % some small positive constant

for k=1:10000,
    [U,S,V]=svd(2*rand(n,n)-1);  % SVD of a random matrix
    AA1=diag(rand(n,1));         % A_1^2
    AA2=U*diag(rand(n,1))*U';
    AA3=V*diag(rand(n,1))*V';
    x=2*rand(n,1)-1;
    y=2*rand(n,1)-1;
    z=2*rand(n,1)-1;
    B1=sqrtm(AA1+t*x*x');  % thus B_1^2>=A_1^2
    B2=sqrtm(AA2+t*y*y');
    B3=sqrtm(AA3+t*z*z');
    A1=sqrtm(AA1);
    A2=sqrtm(AA2);
    A3=sqrtm(AA3);
    r=norm(A1*A2*A3,'fro')/norm(B1*B2*B3,'fro')-1;
    if r>0,
        A1,A2,A3,B1,B2,B3,r,break;
    end;
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If $$||B_1\cdots B_n||_F=||B_1||_F\cdots||B_n||_F$$
holds, then the inequality is easy to prove:

For a $m\times m$ matrix, the Frobenius norm can be expressed as
$$||A||_F=\sqrt{\sum \sigma_k^2(A)},$$
where $\sigma_k(A)$, $1\leq k\leq m$, are the eigenvalues of $AA^T$ (search Frobenius norm in [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm) page of Wikipedia).

We can use [Weyl's inequality](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl%27s_inequality) to deduce that
$$\sigma_k(A_i)<\sigma_k(B_i),$$
where $\sigma_k$ are ordered in increasing size. Therefore,
\begin{align*}||A_1\cdots A_n||_F^2&\leq ||A_1||_F^2\cdots||A_n||_F^2\\&=
\left(\sum \sigma_k^2(A_1)\right)\cdots\left(\sum  \sigma_k^2(A_n)\right)\\&<\left(\sum \sigma_k^2(B_1)\right)\cdots\left(\sum \sigma_k^2(B_n)\right)\\
&=||B_1||^2_F\cdots||B_n||^2_F\\
&=||B_1\cdots B_n||^2_F.\end{align*}

**PD:** I think this restriction I've assumed is quite difficult to achieve, so this result might not be really helpful.

Comment: I'm afraid $\|B_1B_2\cdots B_n\|_F=\|B_1\|_F\|B_2\|_F\cdots\|B_n\|_F$ is an impossible condition unless the matrices are $1\times1$. Since
$$
\|B_1B_2\cdots B_n\|_F
\le\|B_1B_2\|_F\big(\|B_3\|_F\cdots\|B_n\|_F\big)
\le\|B_1\|_F\|B_2\|_F\big(\|B_3\|_F\cdots\|B_n\|_F\big),
$$
if the LHS is equal to the RHS, we must have $\|B_1B_2\|_F=\|B_1\|_F\|B_2\|_F$. ...

Comment: ...Therefore
$$
\begin{aligned}
\|B_1\|_F^2\|B_2\|_F^2
&=\|B_1B_2\|_F^2\\
&=\operatorname{tr}\big((B_1B_2)(B_2B_1)\big)
=\operatorname{tr}(B_1^2B_2^2)\\
&=\langle B_1^2,B_2^2\rangle_F\\
&\le\|B_1^2\|_F\|B_2^2\|_F\\
&\le\|B_1\|_F^2\|B_2\|_F^2.
\end{aligned}
$$
Hence $\|B_1^2\|_F=\|B_1\|_F^2$, i.e., $\sqrt{\sum_i\lambda_i^4}=\sum_i\lambda_i^2$ where the $\lambda_i$s are the eigenvalues of $B_1$. This is impossible if $B_1$ is at least $2\times2$, because $\lambda_i>0$.